# Failed to parse Json into Html via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following JavaScript function that is called onload of an HTML page, but my data isn't parsing nor anything can be written in html through this function:

```
function displaySearchResults(){
    //link base para a realização de requests para a API
    var requestBaseURL = "https://api.predicthq.com/v1/events?";

    var startDate = "start.gte=" + sessionStorage.getItem("startDate") + "&";
    var endDate = "start.lte=" + sessionStorage.getItem("endDate") + "&";
    var eventType = "category=" + sessionStorage.getItem("eventType") + "&";
    var countrySearch = "country=" + sessionStorage.getItem("countrySearch");

    var requestURL = requestBaseURL + startDate + endDate + eventType + countrySearch;

    var searchRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    searchRequest.withCredentials = false;

    searchRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(data);
        //TODO parse data into lists with associated buttons
        var result = data.results
        var msg = ""
        for (var i=0;i < result.length;i++) {
            msg += ("<li>" + result[i].title + "</li>\n");
        }
        msg = "<li>END</li>"
        document.getElementsById("searchResults").innerHTML=msg;
}
    });
}
```

Nor any data from the request nor de END msg is passing to the this HTML page:

(...)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="displaySearchResults()">
    <header id="header">

    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h5>Resultados:</h5>
            <ul id="searchResults">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ive tried calling it at the end and after the body tag, same result. If its on load why doesn't appear anything, also console shows no errors.

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `XMLHttpRequest` and not `fetch`? Did you debug at all? What is the value of `this.responseText`?

Comment: I dont see a `searchRequest.open(...)`, or a `searchRequest.send(...)` both are needed for `XMLHttpRequest` to set and start the request.

Comment: Did you forget `+=` in the last assignment to `msg`?? Seems typo

Comment: @PatrickEvans I have it after that javascript sample code, I just didn't paste it

Comment: Your `if` condition should probably include `this.status`, like `this.readyState === this.DONE && this.status === 200`, so that you know the request succeeded.

Comment: @trincot I changed it and the result is the same , I also use XMLHttpRequest because that's how I learned it and the value of this.respondeText is as expected, just checked with console.log

Comment: Please update your question with that fix, and please add a short example value for `data` (`this.responseText`). If that value is really correct, then the problem is unrelated to the HTTP request, and you should update your question to exclude that. Just make sure the problem is reproducible. Did you check that the code in the listener actually runs?

Comment: I found the problem ( Duh ) ... on the end of the javascript function i have getElements instead of getElement . Srry to bother yall

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It has a button which on click render the List in dom.

```js
var data = {
  results: [{
    title: "title1"
  }, {
    title: "title2"
  }, {
    title: "title3"
  }]
}


function LoadResult() {
  var result = data.results
  var msg = "<ul>"
  result.forEach(s => {
    msg = msg + "<li>" + s.title + "</li>"
  })
  msg = msg + "<li>END</li></ul>"
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <button onClick="LoadResult()">Load</button>
  <div id="result">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1.Mgs was getting overridden when adding the END text. 2. `\n` was not required to be added for each loop.